# Sum Of n numbers taken $k$ at a time, where numbers are of form $r\choose k$

Tags: combinatorics

I have an array of numbers lets call it $p$ , where $p[r]={k+r-1\choose k-1}$

I want to find the sum of all the elements of $p$ taken $n$ at a time .

$0\le r\le k$

For instance, for $k=3$ ,$n=2$ , i need

$$p[0]^2+p[1]^2+p[2]^2+p[3]^2+p[0]\cdot p[1]+p[0]\cdot p[2]+p[0]\cdot p[3]+p[1]\cdot p[2]+p[1]\cdot p[3]+\\+p[2]\cdot p[3]=\sum_{i\le j}p[i]\cdot p[j]=\sum_{i\le j}{k+i-1\choose k-1}{k+j-1\choose k-1}$$ which is $273$

Is there any way , i can solve this for any value of $k$ or $n$ without solving big equations like above

Comment: I took the liberty to write some of your notation in a more synthetic way which I thought to be of more immediate understanding. Fell free to tell me to undo part of it.

Comment: Something is wrong in your calculations, $p[3]$ is $\binom{6}{3}=20$ and $20^2=400$ so your sum should be $400$. I have a general formula for your sum but I would like a clarification before I publish it. I'll add it when you have fixed the problem with the sum.

Comment: Thanks @G.Sassatelli for the corrections , I am new here , so I didnt know the formatting techniques .

Comment: @Gamamal , you are right , i made the appropriate corrections , sorry for the mistake !

Comment: Why is the sum only $273$ ?? isn't $p[3]=20$? This alone makes the sum larger than $20^2=400$

Comment: $p[3]=\binom{5}{2}=10$

Comment: @Gamamal .. I made the correction , instead p[3]=10 , not 20 !